# Simple bash script taking too long to execute

Tags: files, performance, cp

I wrote the following function in my `.bashrc` for use instead of `rm *` :

```
function re()
{
   cp . -R /home/glset/ritwik/trash/
   rm *
}
```

It works .. but it is very slow. Even for small files it takes too long to execute. It is always faster to just fire the two commands one after the other which defeats the purpose of the function in the first place. Am I doing something wrong here ? What makes it take longer ?

Comment: There is a minor strangeness there: you `cp` recursively, but not `rm` recursively. Are you sure that is what you want?

Comment: What he really wanted to do was `cp * /path/to/trash/`

Comment: Any particular reason to copy the files and then remove them in stead of removing them. You could get into trouble doing things this way if this is done on the same filesystem and you are running low on disc-space. (It would be faster in that case as well, but it doesn't explain why your function is slow).

Comment: @Anthon the reason for doing this was I wanted to implemented a trash bin and not do rm at all. rm shud be done only inside the trash folder.

Comment: Still one more vote for `mv` instead.

Comment: @RitwikG Sorry The second 'removing' should have read 'moving'  Any particular reason to copy the files and then remove them in stead of **moving** them. You could get into trouble doing things this way if this is done on the same filesystem and you are running low on disc-space. (It would be faster in that case as well, but it doesn't explain why your function is slow).

Comment: You can check if the `trash` command from the `trash-cli` package might be useful for you.

Comment: Have you tried running the script through `strace`? Maybe it can give you a clue as to what is happening.

Answer (score 3):

Running the function or running the two commands separately does not make any measurable difference in execution time.

My guess would be that you ran the function, found that it was slow, then tried the commands separately.

If you did that, then it's likely that the first time, the data was not present in the disk cache, so what you measured was the time to load the data from the disk. The second time, the data was already in the disk cache (because you had just accessed it), so you measured the time to copy the data around in memory.

To do proper benchmarks, you need to start all measurements in the same conditions: either you know that all the data is in the cache, or you know that all the data has to be loaded from the disk.

---

Copying the data and then removing the original is a really weird way of doing this. Run `mv` instead! It's instantaneous if you've moving the files inside the same filesystem.

Furthermore, `rm *` is a very unusual command. If you don't need a directory anymore, remove the directory: `rm -r somedir` or `mv somedir ~/trash/`.